# UWP: Error when referencing Views from seperate repo

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a normal UWP project but I've broken the Application, Views, ViewModels, Models, etc. into their own repositories.

When I reference the View (Page) from the Views repository I get an error |An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'".

If I make the view in the Application level of the project I don't get the error.  My repository is a class library and all are pointing to the same Windows 10 version.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a colleague of mine actually found the answer for me.  It's more of a hack but it works.  I can't explain definitely why this works but I have an assumption.  I'll leave the assumption to myself....

To make this work, open your App.xaml file and add the namespace to the Views repository.

```
xmlns:Views="using:Views"
```

Then make a dummy resource to the main view in that repository (or any view I'm assuming.)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Views:MainPage x:Key="mainPage" />
</Application.Resources>
```

For some reason this makes everything work like a charm... I know it's a hack but it's simple and clean enough that I've bought it and moved on.